# perpendicular distance between point and line

Tags: math, distance

I have an equation I want to use it in my research to find the distance between a point and a line that is defined by two points. The equation is found in wikipedia, but I cannot find the name of the equation to use it as a reference in my research. Can some one help me in find that?

The equation is :

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rksWO.png)

in the link :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not: "Point-Line minimum distance"?

Answer (score 0):

'Perpendicular Distance from a Point to a Line' 
This is the minimum distance from a point to a line